# django redirect inside of urls.py

Tags: python, django

I plan on having several different apps inside my django project, each for a new technology I want to play around with. As I work on each on, I want to have the root URL path redirect to the project I'm working on.

Directory Structure:

```
backyard/
    my_project/
        views.py
    backyard/
        urls.py
```

backyard/backyard/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.shortcuts import redirect

urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^$', redirect('my_app/')),
    url(r'^my_project/$', 'my_project.views.homepage'),

)
```

backyard/my_project/views.py

```
def homepage(request):
    return render_to_response('my_project/index.html', {'data':data})
```

When I access the page at `http:machine-name:8000/` I get an error saying `The included urlconf backyard.urls doesn't have any patterns in it` I most definitely have URLs in my urls.py, what is the issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A URLconf needs to map regexes to views -- the `redirect` function doesn't return a view; rather, it returns an `HttpResponse`. You can look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14959217/django-url-redirect) for an example of how to define a redirect directly in the URLconf.

Comment: Sry, it is like that. I should have included it. Please see my edit.

Comment: @jefffabiny That will just give you a syntax error at the import statement.

Comment: Correct. I'm going too fast here for my own good... Again, it is like that in my file. I've corrected it again.

Comment: @jefffabiny Okay, I guess it's just a weird error message then. It'll work if you use a `RedirectView` like in the linked question.