# django - redirect to a page after registering a user

Tags: django, django-registration

After a user successfully registers an account (creates a username and password) the webpage returns a blank registration form.

I would like to redirect to the 'landingpage' url after successful registration.

Here is the html form:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'register' %}">
{% csrf_token %}
  <table>{{ form.as_table }}</table>
    <input type="submit" value="register" />
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
</form>
```

and urls.py:

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

urlpatterns = [
url('^accounts/register/', CreateView.as_view(
        template_name='registration/register.html',
        form_class=UserCreationForm,
        success_url='landingpage'
), name='register'),
url('^accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
url(r'^$', views.landingpage, name='landingpage'), ]
```

Should the success_url='landingpage' redirect to the landingpage url?

How do I redirect to the landingpage url after a successful registration?

Comment: you can use https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/base/#redirectview or this post is similar to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14959217/django-url-redirect/31302965

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the `reverse_lazy` function, it is included inside the `django.core.urlresolvers` and must be imported using `from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy`

The code should be similar to:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
# more code goes here
    url('^accounts/register/', CreateView.as_view(
        template_name='registration/register.html',
        form_class=UserCreationForm,
        success_url=reverse_lazy('landingpage')  # note the usage of reverse_lazy here 
    ), name='register'),
# also here
```

That function will traverse your urls and make the proper redirection after success registration.

Take a look at the django docs for more options: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse-lazy

Comment: `from django.urls import reverse_lazy` for django 2+