# Django URL Redirects And Changing URL Structure

Tags: django, url-rewriting, url-routing

I'm trying to get some information before i change the URL structure of my website.

I want to better organize the overall folder system for my 'deals website.

currently my urls look like this

for a specific deal : `deals/discount-bike-at-walmart-99`

for a specific category: `deals/category/apparel`

for a specific retailer: `deals/retailer-deals/walmart`

i feel like maybe these folders are a bit too long

if i do want to change them, does django allready handle the redirects or is there something I need to do handle this?  my site is allready indexed by google, so i'm trying to avoid an issue where I'm creating duplicated content

Comment: is the number at the end an ID as argument?`deals/discount-bike-at-walmart-99`?

Comment: No that was just an example—just text from page title

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django URL Redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14959217/django-url-redirect)

Comment: If you want to change the locations of `views` python file at the project directory you will have to edit the `urls.py`  at the project level and so as at the module level. if the indexing with google is done already just use `redirectView` concept in Django

Answer (score 0):

Try [redirectView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/base/#redirectview) to direct your client side URL calls to newly changed `view` python files. From that way you want be changing the indexed done with google on your website

Comment: thanks for this...one question.  i had to move some of my urls that i need to redirect to another app.  so, this is example:  
`path('<slug:slug>/', RedirectView.as_view(pattern_name='deal_detail', permanent=False)),`

Comment: problem is that it is saying that reverse for deal_detail is not found ...even though i'm importing my other url file like this `from dealmazing.urls import *`