# How to redirect ?page=1 to / in Django paginations?

Tags: django, django-views

I am a little confused why my view code does not work. I need to redirect whenever /?page=1 to just /

My view:

```
blogs = models.BlogPost.objects.filter(is_active = True).order_by('-pub_date')
paginator = Paginator(blogs, 12)
page_number = request.GET.get('page')

#THIS IS THE PART THAT DOES NOT WORK#
if page_number == 1:
    redirect('blog:blog', permanent=True)
try:
    page_obj = paginator.page(page_number)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    paginator.get_page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    raise Http404('<h1>Page not found</h1>')
```

If I enter domain.com/?page=1 it should redirect to domain.com/

But it stays domain.com/?page=1

I don't see what I am missing, can someone help me please?

Comment: What is the problem with having `?page=1` anyway?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat the SEO guy says that is wrong, google will see two identical pages

Comment: `request.GET.get('page')` would return a string, you compare it with an integer.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I have tried comparing to '1' and also tried to use int() on page_number. Nothing had worked

Comment: I tested it, works properly... Try `print(type(page_number), page_number)` What do you get?

Answer (score 0):

you could use [redirecview](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/base/#redirectview) to redirect any url to another one. e.g. [Django URL Redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14959217/django-url-redirect/31302965)